# I have been using the store to download,ever since i restarted my phone i can't download.it want me to change family setting

Tags: apps, store

I want to download...when ever am trying my phone tells me to go to www.windowsphone.com/my family and sign in with my account to change the setting but I can not find the setting and I don't know what to do now I've been trying but I can't get it done [image]

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to your Microsoft account, its privacy settings don't allow a child account to make purchases online, thus Microsoft recognizes that your child is a minor and won’t allow them to download a paid application on their Windows Phone. You can only download free apps and not paid ones, or some free apps can't be downloaded if the age set in your account is below the minimum age to use that app.

You can find how to fix this reading [this article](http://www.mobilityminded.com/13571/how-to-enable-app-purchases-for-your-childrens-windows-phones/).